# Decompose a vector space into invariant subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, galois-theory

Consider the following proposition:

> Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and $K/F$ is a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. If $V$ has a $(K,K)$ bimodule structure compatible with the vector space structure, i.e. $rv=vr$ for each $r\in F$ and $v\in V$, and $V_g=\{\, v\in V \colon\forall c\in K,cv=v(gc)\,\}$, then $V=\bigoplus_{g\in G}V_g$.

I hope it's true and I need a more conceptual way to describe it. I don't know how to do this. I need some help or hint.

Here's the background for the proposition. In complex geometry, we usually complexificate a finite dimensional real vector space $V$ along with a [linear complex structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) $J$: $V_{\mathbb C}=V\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$. We decompose the complexification as $V_{\mathbb C}=V^{1,0}\oplus V^{0,1}$ where $V^{1,0}$ is the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $i$ for $J\otimes\mathbb C\colon V_{\mathbb C}\to V_{\mathbb C}$. More generally, I have shown that

> If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $K$, and $K/F$ is a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$, then we can decompose $V\otimes_FK$ as $\bigoplus_{g\in G}V_g$ where $V_g$ is the totality of $\sum_jv_j\otimes k_j$ such that $\sum_jcv_j\otimes k_j=\sum_jv_j\otimes (gc)k_j$.

I constructed concrete projections $V\otimes_F K\to V_g$ in aid of a basis $x_1,\dotsc,x_d$ of $K$ as a $F$-vector space and its dual basis $y_1,\dotsc,y_d$ with respect to the nondegenerate trace pairing $\langle r,s\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}_{K/F}(rs)$ for $r,s\in K$. I think there's a more conceptual method to describe such a fact, and I believe there's a more conceptual proof, without appealing to clumsy expressions involving $x_1,\dotsc,x_d,y_1,\dotsc,y_d$. Meanwhile, I'm too green to spell it out.